# IOS error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' in ionic3?

Tags: ios, webview, ionic3, wkwebview

On iOS 9.0 my app is terminated just after launch, with this message in xcode

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

I tried each and everything for solve above error but nothing worked for.i am using background mode plugin for for get location in background mode.i tried below soltion's:

**Tried Solution**

**1st solution:**

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/419

> Removing lines APPBackgroundMode.m:266 & 267: [obj setValue:[NSNumber
>   numberWithBool:YES] <--- remove! forKey:[APPBackgroundMode
>   wkProperty]]; <--- remove!

**2nd solution:**

Try in file src\ios\APPBackgroundMode.m replace following lines

```
+ (NSString*) wkProperty {
    NSString* str = @"YWx3YXlzUnVuc0F0Rm9yZWdyb3VuZFByaW9yaXR5";
    NSData* data  = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; }
```

Below we have mentioned the config.xml file

```
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>This App wants to track your location</string>
</edit-config>
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="~1.5.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="~2.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-document-viewer" spec="~0.9.10" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="~0.9.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.7.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker" spec="~2.2.2">
    <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your usage message" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" spec="^1.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="4.0.11" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" spec="^0.3.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="2.3.0">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION" value="16.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="3.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" spec="2.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="0.7.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="2.3.6">
    <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
    <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
    <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
    <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
    <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app always requires location tracking" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="0.9.0-beta.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="4.1.1">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
```

i tried all solution but nothing worked for me please team help me how to fix?

Comment: Please share more details like:
 - Code from AppDelegate
 - Details of the first view controller to be displayed
 - Programming Language Objective-C or Swift
 - Xcode version
 - Details of privacy strings from info.plist. This is very important as the app will crash if you try to access user location without permission.

Comment: Ok I will update my fiddle

Comment: Kapil, you can answer your own question. So please move your comment to answer and if possible mark as correct answer. This will help others to know that this is solved problem.

Comment: @PankajKulkarni :ok sir i will thanks

Answer (score 1):

finally i fixed above issue after disabled WKWebView and use UIWebView in config.xml (tested only in ionic 3 not ionic4)

```
 <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" >
```